# Can't find where __vfs_read() function calls ext4_file_read_iter() function in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, file, kernel, vfs

So far, I learned that read(2) function call stack are as follows :
read(2) --> SYS_read() --> vfs_read() --> __vfs_read() --> ext4_file_read_iter()

And I have no idea how __vfs_read() function calls ext4_file_read_iter() function.

This is the code of __vfs_read in Kernel code.

```
ssize_t __vfs_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count,
           loff_t *pos)
{
    if (file->f_op->read)
        return file->f_op->read(file, buf, count, pos);
    else if (file->f_op->read_iter)
        return new_sync_read(file, buf, count, pos);
    else
        return -EINVAL;
}
```

And this is for ext4_file_read_iter().

```
static ssize_t ext4_file_read_iter(struct kiocb *iocb, struct iov_iter *to)
{
    if (unlikely(ext4_forced_shutdown(EXT4_SB(file_inode(iocb->ki_filp)->i_sb))))
        return -EIO;

    if (!iov_iter_count(to))
        return 0; /* skip atime */

#ifdef CONFIG_FS_DAX
    if (IS_DAX(file_inode(iocb->ki_filp)))
        return ext4_dax_read_iter(iocb, to);
#endif
    return generic_file_read_iter(iocb, to);
}
```

I have enough intelligence thanks to google that __vfs_read() calls ext4_file_read_iter(), but I am not able to find any link between those two.

Which part in __vfs_read() calls ex4_file_read_iter()?

This bothers me. Any help please...

Currently, I am now using

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source

This web for dive into the Linux Kernel source..

Comment: Seems simple to me: `__vfs_read()` -> `new_sync_read()` -> `call_read_iter()` -> `ext4_file_read_iter()`

Comment: Do you understand how `if (file->f_op->read) return file->f_op->read(file, buf, count, pos);` might transfer control to a function named `ext4_file_read`, if ext4 had that rather than `ext4_file_read_iter`?

Comment: @zwol I think I dont catch it. Could you elaborate that a bit more for me? Thank you so much

Comment: OK, this is a very basic C question at heart.  You need to understand the concept of _function pointers_.  I'm not finding a good explanation of that on this site, so I can only suggest you consult a C textbook.

Comment: @Eric: The function `call_read_iter`, called by `new_sync_read`, [executes](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1866) `file->f_op->read_iter(kio, iter);`. This is a call by a pointer, and the pointer is set by ext4 driver to `ext4_file_read_iter`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for your comment.. still I don't get it 100%. file->f_op->read_iter(Kio, iter); makes call read_iter() and then, I can't understand "the pointer is set by ext4 driver" . Where are those settings done? Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Where are those settings done?" - Those settings are done by `ext4` driver. You probably want to read about VFS (Virtual File System) - this is a way how Linux works with filesystems. Just try to google some article about it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev got it finally.. Thank you so much for your help!